# Express wildcard GET breaks routing to React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I am developing my project starting from this React-Webpack boilerplate repo (https://github.com/wallacyyy/webpack-heroku/blob/master/server.js). Everything works as expected but now, I would like to implement routing inside my React app, and to do that, I have to modify the previous file (`server.js`) to the following:

Instead of :

```
app.get('/', function (_, res) { res.sendFile(indexPath) })
```

I use:

```
app.get('*', function (_, res) { res.sendFile(indexPath) })
```

As soon as I do this change, everything breaks and the React app does not render anymore. The only thing I get is an error in the browser: `bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and if I try to see the contents of `bundle.js` I get the contents of `index.html`.

Any idea why the wildcard routing of express breaks the React app?

Comment: Sounds like doing so is breaking the proper serving of your assets, such as bundle.js. If you were serving static assets with, say, nginx, and then proxying everything else to node, this wouldn't happen. another "fix" would be to ensure your static file routes come before your wildcard.

Comment: Could you tell me how to achieve the latter?

Comment: Have you tried loading this from publicPath instead of indexPath?  Doing that you'll need to add <div id="main"></div> to the publicPath index.html.  I am wondering if like Kevin said it has to do with rendering static files.

Comment: `index.html` is outside of the public directory. I think the problem is where webpack stores its result because I am using `webpackDevMiddleware`.

Comment: As an update, I also tried moving `index.html` inside the `public` directory and point the `res.sendFile` there but the result was unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware/issues/26#issuecomment-144941322), `webpack-hot-middleware` configuration needs to come before the `*` handler so it can match the path. After finding out this information, the fix was quite trivial, I moved the configuration of `webpack-hot-middleware` before the GET handler.